# Countable collection of Borel subsets of $[0, 1]$, exists subsequence where $\int_A f_{n_j}(x)\,dx$ converges for each $i$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, measure-theory

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of measurable real-valued functions on $[0, 1]$ that is uniformly bounded. How do I see that if $\{A_i\}$ is a countable collection of Borel subsets of $[0, 1]$, then there exists a subsequence $n_j$ such that $\int_{A_i} f_{n_j}(x)\,dx$ converges for each $i$?

Answer (score 1):

This can be proven with a diagonalization argument.

In order to simplify the notation I will write $a(i, n) = \int_{A_i} f_n \; d\lambda$.

Note that $a(1, n)$ is a bounded sequence and we can therefore find a subsequence $a(1, k_1(n))$ that converges. Now we can also find a subsequence $k_2(n)$ of $k_1(n)$ so that $a(2, k_2(n))$ converges (by the same argument). Continuing with this construction gives us a *sequence of sequences* $k_l(n)$ such that $k_l$ is a subsequence of $k_{l - 1}$ and $a(l, k_l(n))$ converges for $n \to \infty$. Now using the definition of convergence you can show that all the sequences $a(l, k_n(n))$ converge for $n \to \infty$.

Comment: So you have a infinite number of subsequences, how do you know that you final subsequence is not empty?

Comment: I choose a "diagonal" sequence, $k_n(n)$.